# tree.xpath grab text value

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i have a code thats was working fine until a few days ago.

it's navigate in a web page and scrap the values.

the code is

```
ValorAtual = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main-2"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/strong')[0].text
```

but now it's returning me `[]`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-da7aa636e9c1> in <module>
     70     Dividend_Yield = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main-2"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/strong')
     71 
---> 72     Proventos_Pagos12Meses = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main-2"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/span[2]')[0].text
     73 
     74     PL = tree.xpath('//*[@id="indicators-section"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/strong')[0].text

IndexError: list index out of range
```

the full Xpath is

```
/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/strong
```

And the path is

```
//*[@id="main-2"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/strong
```

the website is https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/aalr3

A way to grab the data

Comment: Most likely the page layout has changed. What text data did you receive? Look in the debugger which way to them now.

Comment: but now it's returning me []